# How to run an external file from within the scala interactive interpreter (REPL)?

Tags: scala, interpreter, read-eval-print-loop

I have a file with several lines of scala code -- imports, list value assignments, etc. that I often use to initialize some things when using the REPL.

Currently I just open up the file in a text editor and copy-and-paste it into the REPL, but is there a way to do it by calling the external file in a more direct manner so I don't have to copy-and-paste every time?

In some interactive database tools like SQL Plus, it is done by typing `@filename` at the prompt.  Is there something similar in the Scala REPL?  Preceding the filename with `@` doesn't work, `eval` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Type:

```
:help
```

and you see, that

```
:load <path>               load and interpret a Scala file
```

solves your problem.

In some circumstances, pasting the code might be preferable though, but then

```
:paste
```

might be your friend then. It helps inserting a whole block without feedback, line by line, until you hit  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>D</kbd>. In some cases this is significant for the code interpretation.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!   I can't find documentation of the REPL anywhere on the web.  I didn't even know that `:help` would show the (limited) help; I was trying other things like `scala /?` and `scala -help` at the Windows command prompt, and `help` and `?` within the REPL.

Comment: Where did you learn about `:paste`?  It's not listed with `:help`.  Apparently you have access to documentation that I don't know about.  I also wonder what `:power` is about.

Comment: `:paste` is new in 2.9.something, I guess 2.9.1. `:power` is a bit older, I never used it, except to see what it is. I guess I know it from the mailinglist. From the scala homepage I can't find a brief documentation about `:power` or the REPL.

Comment: @Gigatron It says so when you start REPL: `Type :help for more information.`

Comment: Somehow I didn't notice it.  I guess it's because I always immediately copy-and-paste from that file I was talking about, and everything scrolls up and offscreen before I read the boilerplate text.